# Game directed software questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want help installing lubbofancontrol under bootcamp on my mac for the specific reason that it should increase gaming performance.  Should I ask that here or on superuser?

I know it's a SU-compatible question more than a gaming question, but the only reason I'm asking is that it is a piece of software that would mainly be important for gamers, and people on this site would be the most likely to want to know the answer.

In general, I'm wondering about questions which, while they may be general support questions, pertain specifically to gamers, such as hardware optimization for games, [steam issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/failed-to-load-web-page-unknown-error-118) etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can state it in more general terms than "I need to play this game" it can be OK on SU.

Basically, from my perspective, it *sounds* like "how do I set my CPU fan to always on so I can run CPU intensive applications at maximum speed?" but that's just a guess.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but something like Steam [for example this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/failed-to-load-web-page-unknown-error-118) is game specific.